# How to implement a "processing request"-message in TkInter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to implement a popup-window, which should display over the main window, while an operation is taking place in the background. Pressing the button from the code below results in freezing the GUI for 10s without displaying any message and eventually making the button green. The freezing is normal, but I would like to have the popup displayed during the 10 seconds.
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button1 = tk.Button(text="Start", command=self.make_green)
        self.button1.pack()


    def popup(self):
        tl = tk.Toplevel(self)
        tl.transient()
        tk.Label(tl, text="Painting green").pack()
        tl.grab_set()
        return tl

    def make_green(self):
        wait_popup = self.popup()
        time.sleep(10)
        self.button1.config(bg="green")
        wait_popup.destroy()

a = GUI()
a.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use self.update() in your code to make the popup window appear.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button1 = tk.Button(text="Start", command=self.make_green)
        self.button1.pack()


    def popup(self):
        tl = tk.Toplevel(self)
        tl.transient()
        tk.Label(tl, text="Painting green").pack()
        self.update()
        tl.grab_set()
        return tl

    def make_green(self):
        wait_popup = self.popup()
        time.sleep(10)
        self.button1.config(bg="green")
        wait_popup.destroy()

a = GUI()
a.mainloop()
```

Or you can use threading.

Start by importing Thread from threading.

```
from threading import Thread
```

Then make a new method

```
def thread_it(self):
    return Thread(target=self.make_green, daemon=True).start()
```

and update your button's command

```
self.button1 = tk.Button(text="Start", command=self.thread_it)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The second approach with threading solved my problem.